# Custom suspend mode (dev only) discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

my friend used a similar thing in his discord bot, this is my code and no matter what the bot is always in suspend mode:

```
const { Client, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const { TOKEN, PREFIX, DEV_ID, DEV_PREFIX } = require("./config.json");

client.login(TOKEN);
client.suspend = false

//other client.on code

client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(DEV_PREFIX) && message.author.id == DEV_ID && message.content.includes("suspend")) {
        if (client.suspend = false) {
            client.suspend = true;
            message.channel.send("Suspend mode on!")
        } else if (client.suspend = true) {
            client.suspend = false;
            message.channel.send("Suspend mode off!")
        } else {
            message.channel.send("AHH THERE WAS AN ERROR!!")
            client.suspend = false;
        }
    } 
    if (client.suspend = false) {
    //bot's commands and other functions of the bot that can be turned off during suspend.
    }
```

expected outcome, `//suspend` toggles suspend mode, current outcome, bot doesn't listen for commands, suspend mode is always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you didn't set who the bot owner or dev is, so even if you're the bot owner, you won't be able to run the command, any command except suspend, since you set it. Also, you're trying to check if you can assign variable by using `=` instead of comparing it using `==` or `===`. Try checking out this code below:

---

```js
const { Client, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const { TOKEN, PREFIX, DEV_ID, DEV_PREFIX } = require("./config.json");

client.login(TOKEN);
client.suspend = false

// other client.on code

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(DEV_PREFIX) && message.author.id == DEV_ID && message.content.includes("suspend")) {

    // Quick Tip : You can use `client.suspend` to
    // check if it's true and `!client.suspend` to check if it's false.

    if (!client.suspend) {
      client.suspend = true;
      message.channel.send("Suspend mode on!")
    } else if (client.suspend) {
      client.suspend = false;
      message.channel.send("Suspend mode off!")
    } // You don't need else again.
  } 

  // Allow the dev to run the command in or out of suspension, and
  // allow all users to use the command if it's not suspended.
  if ((client.suspend && message.author.id == DEV_ID) || (!client.suspend)) {
    // Your commands here, all of it... Only Devs can use it, otherwise, separate
    // all of your commands into ones that can be used by devs in suspension, and
    // ones that can be used by users during suspension.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't check in your ifs, you assign: In JavaScript, you compare using `==`, while `=` is used to assign a value: You don't check if it's false, you set it to false. The correct assignments would look like this:

```js
const { Client, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const { TOKEN, PREFIX, DEV_ID, DEV_PREFIX } = require("./config.json");

client.login(TOKEN);
client.suspend = false

//other client.on code

client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(DEV_PREFIX) && message.author.id == DEV_ID && message.content.includes("suspend")) {
        if (!client.suspend) {
            client.suspend = true;
            message.channel.send("Suspend mode on!")
        } else {
            client.suspend = false;
            message.channel.send("Suspend mode off!")
        } 
    } 
    if (!client.suspend) { //shorthand for == false
    //bot's commands and other functions of the bot that can be turned off during suspend.
    }
});
```